# compiling is okay but my program doesn't really work

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (1)   
    {
        char name1[100];
        char adrs1[100];
        char rsn1[100];
        char XXXXX[100];

        cout << "input personal information" << '\n';
        cout << "patient 1" << '\n';
        cout << "input the name of the patient" << '\n';
        cin.getline (name1,100);
        cout << "input the address of the patient" << '\n';
        cin.getline (adrs1,100);
        cout << "input the reason" << '\n';             
        cin.getline (rsn1,100);

        cout << "input the name of the patient" << '\n';
        cout << "if you want to exit, input exit" << '\n';
        cin.getline (XXXXX,100);


        if (XXXXX==name1)
            cout << adrs1[100] << rsn1[100] << '\n';
        else (XXXXX=="exit");
            break;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

that's my program, and compiling is okay. but when i start the program, it doesn't print any rsn or adrs, it just ends.
I want it to print rsn and adrs when it reads names.
Help me please

Comment: Did you try to debug this? for instance what value does `XXXXX` hold? and what is `name1`?

Comment: What you posted [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cec089352f995466).

Comment: For starters, to print anything useful it should be `cout << adrs1 << rsn1 << '\n';` (what you are doing with the `[100]` is printing a single character **outside** each array, which is UB). Also recommend to use `std::string` instead of the raw char arrays.

Comment: You should indent your code for your own sake.

Comment: I have edited your formatting. This will make it easier for people to read you question and make them more likely to take the time to answer.

Comment: _"compiling is okay but my program doesn't really work"_ is an awful title. Questions are supposed to be able to help others in the future. This won't.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few errors in your program.

- The most important one is that you are trying to write an infinite loop. But it runs exactly once. You need to move your return statement out of the loop.
- There is no need for a conditional statement for an else block. You can remove it along with the semi colon.
- You're trying to print a character at the index 100 which goes out of bounds.
- I don't know what XXXXX is supposed to be. May be you missed pasting the declaration on this website.

At this point, I really suggest picking up a book or trying to debug your code by going step-by-step through your code. It would be more helpful to you at this stage in your learning than this website,

Comment: User has given option of exit to come out of loop.

Comment: @Sumeet She always exits on first iteration. The option is useless.

Comment: thank you! I'm really a starer and still learning. This code is part of the larger code, there are more than 5 patients so XXXXX is one of the 5 patient's name. Thank you again :))

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer above, the correct program would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{


while (1)   
{

char name1[100];
char adrs1[100];
char rsn1[100];
char XXXXX[100];

cout << "input personal information" << '\n';
cout << "patient 1" << '\n';
cout << "input the name of the patient" << '\n';
cin.getline (name1,100);
cout << "input the address of the patient" << '\n';
cin.getline (adrs1,100);
cout << "input the reason" << '\n';             
cin.getline (rsn1,100);

cout << "input the name of the patient" << '\n';
cout << "if you want to exit, input exit" << '\n';
cin.getline (XXXXX,100);


if (strcmp(XXXXX,name1) == 0)
cout << adrs1 << rsn1 << '\n';
else /*(XXXXX=="exit");*/
break;

//return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never heard of strcmp, so I'll try to find. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

- You forgot to initilize the `name1` variable, you can initialize it using `char name1[100] = {};`
- You cannot directly compare the `if (XXXXX==name1)`, use can use the `strncmp` function for the same. I will prefer the string class instead of char pointer. Use the following:

  ```
  if (!strncmp(XXXXX,name1,100))
      cout << adrs1 << rsn1 << '\n';
  else if (!strncmp(XXXXX,"exit",100))
      break;
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, now it's working. I'll try to study strncmp! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: My pleasure. Please mark this answer if it solves your problem.